# Intersection of cones and planes

Tags: conic-sections, volume, multiple-integral

I need to calculate the volume of the region bound by :

1. The cone $z^2=x^2+y^2$
2. The plane $z=2x+2y-2$
3. The plane $z=4$

I have already tried setting up a triple integral but I am having some problems determine the upper and lower limits as functions of $y$ and $z$.
I already have the values of $z$ ranging from $(2+4\sqrt 2)/7$ and $4$.

What I have so far :
$$\int_{(2+4\sqrt 2)/7}^4\,\iint f(x,y,z)\,dx\,dy\,dz$$

And I just about managed to compute the bounds for $z$ by equating
$\sqrt{x^2-y^2} = 2x + 2y - 2$, and projecting the resultant hyperbola onto the $xy$–plane to find the vertex.

I'm having trouble determining what the bounds of the inner integrals should be, along with $f(x,y,z)$, what should I do?

Comment: You should really submit your actual working; it's hard to give you advice when we don't know exactly what you've tried

Comment: What do you need to calculate, the volume?

Comment: Indeed I require the volume .

Comment: As for the working , it is really rough so let me summarize what I did .